# WinAPI - CryptDecrypt() not working properly in AES 256

Tags: c, winapi, encryption, aes, wincrypt

I used to work with `crypto++` in *Visual Studio* before, but now I want to use of `wincrypt.h` API functions to encrypt a string with **AES 256** with an **IV** (cbc mode).

I did bellow steps but I'm confused about `CryptEncrypt()` and `CryptDecrypt()` functions, because It seems they don't work properly :

- `CryptAcquireContextA` defined to create a `CSP` :

  ```
  // create a cryptographic service provider (CSP)
  CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)
  ```
- For set key, I'm using of this way (*import key*):

  ```
  CryptImportKey(hProv, (BYTE*)&AESBlob, sizeof(AES256KEYBLOB), NULL, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey)
  ```
- IV, Key, Plaintext sizes are :

  ```
  #define     DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE    32
  #define     DEFAULT_IV_SIZE         16
  #define     BUFFER_FOR_PLAINTEXT    32
  ```

This is my whole `code` :

```
// handles for csp and key
HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
HCRYPTPROV hKey = NULL;
BYTE szKey[DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE + 1] = {0};
BYTE szIV[DEFAULT_IV_SIZE + 1] = {0};
// plain bytes
BYTE szPlainText[BUFFER_FOR_PLAINTEXT + 1] = {0};
DWORD dwPlainSize = 0;

// initalize key and plaintext
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szKey, "00112233445566778899001122334455");
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szIV, "4455667788990011");
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szPlainText, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef");

// blob data for CryptImportKey() function (include key and version and so on...)
struct AES256KEYBLOB
{
    AES256KEYBLOB() { StrCpyA((LPSTR)szBytes, 0); }
    BLOBHEADER bhHdr;
    DWORD dwKeySize;
    BYTE szBytes[DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE + 1];
} AESBlob;

AESBlob.bhHdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
AESBlob.bhHdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
AESBlob.bhHdr.reserved = 0;
AESBlob.bhHdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;
AESBlob.dwKeySize = DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE;
StrCpyA((LPSTR)AESBlob.szBytes, (LPCSTR)szKey);

// create a cryptographic service provider (CSP)
if(CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
{
    if(CryptImportKey(hProv, (BYTE*)&AESBlob, sizeof(AES256KEYBLOB), NULL, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey))
    {
        if(CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_IV, szIV, 0))
        {
            if(CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, szPlainText, &dwPlainSize, lstrlenA((LPCSTR)szPlainText) + 1))
            {
                printf("\nEncrypted data : %s\nSize : %d\n", (LPCSTR)szPlainText, dwPlainSize);

                if(CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, szPlainText, &dwPlainSize)) {
                    printf("\nDecrypted data : %s\nSize : %d\n", (LPCSTR)szPlainText, dwPlainSize);
                }
                else
                    printf("failed to decrypt!");
            }
            else
                printf("failed to encrypt");
        }
    }
}
```

It just encrypt half section of plaintext And decrypting not done! even By changing just `szPlainText` value, it always give me bellow output (It means that `CryptEncrypt()` and `CryptDecrypt()` does not working as expected!) :

```
Encrypted data : U╡π7ÑL|FΩ$}├rUqrstuvwxyzabcdef
Size : 16

Decrypted data : U╡π7ÑL|FΩ$}├rUqrstuvwxyzabcdef
Size : 0
```

Comment: I think you need to copy the key for the decrypt step - encryption morphs the key.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError when i print the key before decrypting, it is correct with out any chenges

Comment: Surely these functions work correctly. Surely the error is in your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I checked every thing. Yes functions working correctly, but i don't know where am i wrong?

Comment: I meant the key handle, hKey, not the actual key.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i checked `hKey`. it has the same value. `if(!hKey) printf("ok");`

Comment: `hKey` is just a handle to the operating system's internal data structure, which holds a copy of the key that you supplied. This is the key that gets morphed.

Comment: It's not your full code. What's `StrCpyA`?

Comment: @CristiFati this function copy the values to `key` , `iv` and `plaintext`

Comment: I read the 3 lines of code as well, and based on its name, i figured out what it's supposed to do, but where is its body, to see what it actually does?

Comment: @CristiFati its in `int main()` body

Comment: As I stated in my previous comment, I noticed where **it's used** (and *BTW*, you **don't have** a `main`), I wanted to see its definition (whether it's a function, a macro, ...). Are you able to provide that? If yes, please include it in the question.

Comment: @CristiFati i included `<shlwapi.h>`, <wincrypt.h>, <stdio.h>

Comment: Oh... *shlwapi* was the missing point. I *Google*d the function and didn't see any results (on the 1st page), that's why I thought it was yours. For testing purposes I ussed: `#define StrCpyA strcpy`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - in general this is true, but here `Final = true` - as result key state reset to intial state

Comment: you wrong called `CryptEncrypt` - last 2 arguments is invalid. `dwPlainSize` - is inout parameter. on input it must containing size of data - so `lstrlenA((LPCSTR)szPlainText) + 1)` - but you pass 0 here (say that you have 0 size data). and the last parameter - must be size of buffer, not size of data

Comment: @RbMm you are absolutely right... i didn't attention to that. but i solved my problem, but now i got it what you said to me. any way thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a variant, that I'm running from *VStudio 2015*.

*code.c*:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

#define DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE 32
#define DEFAULT_IV_SIZE 16
#define BUFFER_FOR_PLAINTEXT 32

#define CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(PROV, KEY) \
    CryptDestroyKey(KEY); \
    CryptReleaseContext(PROV, 0)

#define PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(FUNC) \
    printf("%s (line %d) failed: %d\n", ##FUNC, __LINE__, GetLastError()); \
    return -1


typedef struct AES256KEYBLOB_ {
    BLOBHEADER bhHdr;
    DWORD dwKeySize;
    BYTE szBytes[DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE + 1];
} AES256KEYBLOB;


int main() {
    // handles for csp and key
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
    BYTE szKey[DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
    BYTE szIV[DEFAULT_IV_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
    // plain bytes
    BYTE szPlainText[BUFFER_FOR_PLAINTEXT + 1] = { 0 }, *pBuf = NULL;
    AES256KEYBLOB AESBlob;
    memset(&AESBlob, 0, sizeof(AESBlob));

    // initalize key and plaintext
    StrCpyA((LPSTR)szKey, "00112233445566778899001122334455");
    StrCpyA((LPSTR)szIV, "4455667788990011");
    StrCpyA((LPSTR)szPlainText, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef");
    DWORD dwPlainSize = lstrlenA((LPCSTR)szPlainText), dwBufSize = dwPlainSize, dwBufSize2 = dwPlainSize;

    // blob data for CryptImportKey() function (include key and version and so on...)
    AESBlob.bhHdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
    AESBlob.bhHdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
    AESBlob.bhHdr.reserved = 0;
    AESBlob.bhHdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;
    AESBlob.dwKeySize = DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE;
    StrCpyA((LPSTR)AESBlob.szBytes, (LPCSTR)szKey);

    // create a cryptographic service provider (CSP)
    if (!CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(CryptAcquireContextA);
    }
    if (!CryptImportKey(hProv, (BYTE*)&AESBlob, sizeof(AES256KEYBLOB), NULL, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(CryptImportKey);
    }
    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_IV, szIV, 0)) {
        CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(hProv, hKey);
        PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(CryptSetKeyParam);
    }
    if (CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, &dwBufSize, 0)) {
        printf("%d bytes required to hold the encrypted buf\n", dwBufSize);
        if ((pBuf = calloc(dwBufSize, sizeof(BYTE))) == NULL)
        {
            CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(hProv, hKey);
            PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(calloc);
        }
        StrCpyA(pBuf, szPlainText);
    } else {
        CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(hProv, hKey);
        PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(CryptEncrypt);
    }
    if (CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pBuf, &dwBufSize2, dwBufSize)) {
        printf("\nEncrypted data: [%s]\nSize: %d\n", (LPCSTR)pBuf, dwBufSize2);
        if (CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pBuf, &dwBufSize)) {
            printf("\nDecrypted data: [%s]\nSize: %d\n", (LPCSTR)pBuf, dwBufSize);
        } else {
            free(pBuf);
            CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(hProv, hKey);
            PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(CryptDecrypt);
        }
    } else {
        free(pBuf);
        CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(hProv, hKey);
        PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN(CryptEncrypt);
    }
    free(pBuf);
    CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF(hProv, hKey);
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- Removed *AES256KEYBLOB* constructor as I got *Access Violation* (which is normal when playing with memory "that's not yours"). Replaced the structure initialization with the *memset* call
- The **main** (logical) error was that the buffer was not large enough to store the encrypted text (combined with a wrong value (***0***) for *dwPlainSize* - making the function to misleadingly succeed). According to [[MS.Docs]: CryptEncrypt function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencrypt):

  > If this parameter contains **NULL**, this function will calculate the required size for the ciphertext and place that in the value pointed to by the *pdwDataLen* parameter.

  To find out the required size, make an additional call to the function, with *pbData* set to *NULL* (this practice is also encountered in other *WinAPI*s). Then allocate a buffer, fill it with required data, and make the "main" call the function on that buffer...
- Added the missing *#include*s and *main*
- Added code to release the used resources when no longer needed
- Refacorings:

  - Negated the *if* conditions, since I don't like so many nesting levels
  - Added some convenience macros (*CLEANUP_CRYPT_STUFF*, *PRINT_FUNC_ERR_AND_RETURN*), to avoid code duplication
- Other minor fixes / improvements
- You might want to add a function that prints exactly ***N*** bytes from a buffer, as "***%s***" specifier only stops when "***\0***" is encountered, and only (dumb) luck prevented the console to be filled with garbage (or even the program to crash) when *printf*ing the buffers
- There might be some other aspects related to this functions that I didn't handle (as I'm not an expert in this area), but the goal was just to have smth working

**Output**:

> ```
> 48 bytes required to hold the encrypted buf
>
> Encrypted data: [<É╙åh∩φ:bOPs  r2w~w╪c╟D╡ï╥V╟neΓßv∩·J8cÅ╥²²²²s]
> Size: 48
>
> Decrypted data: [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefΓßv∩·J8cÅ╥²²²²s]
> Size: 32
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: but I didn't know what is this : `CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, &dwBufSize, 0)`

Comment: You're welcome! That's the 2nd bullet: getting the required encrypted buffer size.

Comment: is it store encrypted buffer size in `dwBufSize`?

Comment: Sure (I thought it was obvious).

Comment: by the way, i posted an answer too.

Comment: Hmmm @cristifati, only a few things wrong with the original code then (!)r

Comment: @PaulSanders: I don't understand your comment. I listed everything that I had to do in order to have a compilable and working example. Except for the `if` conditions change (to avoid multiple nesting levels) and convenience macros which are refactors (based on personal preferences), everythiong else was required.

Comment: @PaulSanders Oh... :)) Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

[`CristiFati`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51844463?noredirect=1) answer is great, And it make me offer use of bellow statement for calculate cipher length :

```
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, &dwBufSize, 0);
```

***According Microsoft Doc :***

> If *pbData* is *NULL*, no error is returned, and the function stores the size of the encrypted data, in bytes, in the DWORD value pointed to by pdwDataLen) :

```
BOOL CryptEncrypt(
  HCRYPTKEY  hKey,
  HCRYPTHASH hHash,
  BOOL       Final,
  DWORD      dwFlags,
  BYTE       *pbData,
  DWORD      *pdwDataLen,
  DWORD      dwBufLen
);
```

---

***My Solution :***

But in my code, I just forget to calculate `szPlainText` size when i give it to `CryptEncrypt()` :

```
DWORD dwPlainSize = 0;    // initialized with 0
```

So "zero-length" has not any mean for bellow function (`CryptEncrypt()` function always get a plain-text with `0` length) :

```
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, szPlainText, &dwPlainSize, lstrlenA((LPCSTR)szPlainText) + 1)
```

And I should set its size with bellow statement (My `code` will be worked just by adding this):

```
dwPlainSize = lstrlenA((LPCSTR)szPlainText);
```

Then pass it in right case :

```
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, szPlainText, &dwPlainSize, BUFFER_FOR_PLAINTEXT)
```

So, output is like bellow :

```
Encrypted data : <É╙åh∩φ:bOPs  r2w~w╪c╟D╡ï╥V╟neΓßv∩·J8cÅ╥
Size : 48

Decrypted data : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefΓßv∩·J8cÅ╥
Size : 32
```

Comment: Note that you should also add the resource deallocation (`hProv`, `hKey`).

Comment: @CristiFati sure i did that before in my code, but i forgot to add it in my question. I know this --> `CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0)`

Comment: To print out only the 32 decrypted bytes, try
printf("\nDecrypted data: [%.*s]\nSize: %d\n", dwBufSize, (LPCSTR)pBuf, dwBufSize);